# TF 2.0 GPU cofingure, how to configure the tensorflow-gpu 2.0 and cuda, cudnn after create another virtual environment in pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, tensorflow2.0

I have installed `TensorFlow 1.12` in `Pycharm` using a virtual environment, the `GPU` can work well.
When I create another virtual environment and install `TensorFlow 2.0 Alpha`, the `GPU` doesn't work anymore.

The error:

```
Could not dlopen library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:
```

Comment: TensorFlow 1.12 required CUDA 9.0, TensorFlow 2.0 requires CUDA 10.0. You will need to upgrade to CUDA 10. (And probably use TensorFlow 1.13.1 for a TensorFlow 1.x version that supports CUDA 10)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by adding the below command to the '**.bashrc**' file.

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/

**System configuration:**

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Tensorflow GPU 2.0beta1
Cuda 10.0
cuDNN 7.6.0 for Cuda 10.0
```

I used conda to configure my system.